# AppBar background not changing after changing library for MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Initially `backgroundColor` was working when I had imported AppBar from `@material-ui/core`

But after changing the import to import it from `@mui/material`, it just stays this light blue, must be a default color or something, don't.  But I don't know why backgroundColor no longer has an effect after changing the import.  I changed the library because `borderBottom` wasn't working on the first imported AppBar, but did on the one from `@mui/material`.

I know that in the case after I changed to mui/material that this works:

```
<AppBar className={headerStyles.appBar} position="sticky" sx={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
```

but I still am wondering why it doesn't work with my existing style specified in my makeStyles.

Here are the versions I have installed:

`'@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4"`

`"@mui/material": "^5.15.3"`

```js
<AppBar className={headerStyles.appBar} position="sticky">
```

Why doesn't it work from `headerStyles.appBar` anymore?

```js
const useHeaderStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    appBar: {
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
        zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
        borderBottom: '3px solid orange'
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check where you are importing makeStyles from. According to mui's website, the import has been changed: [Check it out here](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-style-changes/#%E2%9C%85-update-makestyles-import). The new import is

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

Another reason could be: Not using the **Theme Provider**. In mui v5 all useStyles() calls should be inside a  else the makeStyles won't work.
[Read more here](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/)

An example

```
const App = () => {
  return <ThemeProvider><AppBar></ThemeProvider>
}
```

In your AppBar component

```
const AppBar = () => {
  const useHeaderStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  appBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    borderBottom: '3px solid orange'
    }
 })
 const headerStyles = useHeaderStyles()
 return <AppBar className={headerStyles.appBar} position="sticky">
}
```